# For $m$ distinct subsets $A_1,A_2,...,A_m$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $|A_i \cap A_j|=k \neq 0$ for any $i \neq j$, prove $m\leq n$.

Tags: combinatorics

A lovely combinatorial problem:

> For $m$ distinct subsets $A_1,A_2,...,A_m$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $|A_i \cap A_j|=k \neq 0$ for any $i \neq j$,  prove $m\leq n$.

I think some forms of inclusion-exclusion principles may be useful here. Nevertheless, it's unclear to me how to apply. The case that $k=1$ already stumped me. So I started in the reverse order and have figured out the case that $k=n$ or $n-1$ or $n-2$. But it seems hard to argue for general $k$ (maybe backward induction?). Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple idea: you could replace $A_i$ with its complement, replace $\cap$ with $\cup$, and $k$ with $n - k < n$. Don't know if it helps, but it's an idea.

Comment: I don’t have an answer but I’d try induction on $n,$ not on $k.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the "incidence matrix" $M$ of your system. This is the $m\times n$
matrix with a one in position $(i,j)$ if $j\in A_i$ and a zero otherwise. Then
$MM^t$ is an $m\times m$ matrix with diagonal entries $|A_i|>k$ and $k$s elsewhere.
This is a positive definite matrix and so of rank $m$. But if $m>n$, the rank
of $M$ is at most $n$, and so that of $MM^t$ is at most $n$, a contradiction.

Comment: The diagonal is cardinality of A_i but otherwise the argument looks great +1

Comment: @TenaliRaman corrected

Comment: Really? Never thought of linear algebra...

Comment: A small nitpick; $MM^T$ could have one diagonal entry equal to $k$ and the rest greater than $k$. For example, when $n=3,k=1$, you could have $A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{1,3\},A_3=\{1\}$. Such a matrix is still positive.

Comment: For those of us who aren't facile with positive definite matrices, would you (or someone else) mind elaborating how we know that $MM^T$ is positive definite?  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore Represent every set with a boolean vector of size n where 1 at the ith position means element i is present in the set and 0 otherwise. $MM^{\top}$ then is just the gram matrix of m vectors and the gram matrix is positive semi-definite and in this case they are positive definite.